# gcovr - cobertura

Tags: iphone, ios, code-coverage, cobertura, gcov

With gcovr I am able to generate code coverge report(coverage.xml) for my IOS application.How will I use cobertura plugin to convert the coverage.xml to cobertura html report?

Any help appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use the lcov tool suite to generate HTML reports like [these](http://jasperblues.github.io/Typhoon/coverage/index.html). . . The build-script to do this is [here](https://github.com/jasperblues/Typhoon/blob/master/build.xml).

Nice feature: After every build from the build server, the results are uploaded to the Github page.

I was thinking of making a tool to auto-install the script in Xcode. There's an app you can use to view coverage results, but I was after something that:

- Can be run from cmd-line. This makes it compatible with CI build-servers as well as easy to verify results locally.
- lcov can easily be installed via [MacPorts](http://www.macports.org/) or home-brew.

Comment: Is there any way of using cobertura standalone that takes coverage.xml from gcovr without using jenkins to run cobertura and produce the html report ??

Comment: Yes there is. . . I'll update the answer to include that. . . one second:

Comment: Actually, I was going to give you an Ant script to produce HTML but that requires an input file of type .ser. . . it seems you already have the "report", but in XML format. . . However, you could use the Sonar project to transform the XML report to HTML. . That or borrow their XSL style-sheet.

Comment: Is there any XSL file to convert coverage xml report from gcovr to html report of cobertura?

Comment: The HTML report from cobertura is generated internally by the tool. . . I couldn't see an obvious way to get the XSD file, if there is even one. . . the report tool produces two styles of report - HTML or XML. . . its not clear if the HTML step uses XML an an intermediate step. . would have to check the source code. . . . Were you able to get HTML reports via the XML report?

Comment: I was not able to get html report from xml report. html is the default report type for cobertura. Is there any connection between .jelly files inside the cobertura source and html report generation?

Comment: Sorry, I haven't looked at the Cobertura source. . . yes, I'm aware that html is the default format. . XML only useful for eg CI server. . . to get from XML to HTML you just need a stylesheet.